# What does "rules are not decree or routine so much as the starker demands of what’s possible" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the emphasized part (the sentence in bold) mean?

> The hackers are the technicians of this science - “It’s a term of
>   derision and also the ultimate compliment.” They are the ones who
>   translate human demands into code that the machines can understand and
>   act on. They are legion. Fanatics with a potent new toy. A mobile
>   new-found elite, with its own apparat, language and character, its own
>   legends and humor. Those magnificent men with their flying machines,
>   scouting a leading edge of technology which has an odd softness to it;
>   outlaw country, **where rules are not decree or routine so much as the
>   starker demands of what’s possible.**

Answer (score 2):

It means that in the mentioned metaphorical country (the hackerdom), the rules are not precise or strict. Rules are not a usual. In this world, the importance of rules cannot be compared to the enormous opportunities (*what's possible*).

Comment: Perhaps what I wrote is too literal. Rephrased.

Comment: No, rules are not in demand. Rules are neither decree nor routine; and such decree or routine is not so much as [the demand of what's possible].

Comment: The passage focuses only on them (the hackers), so it doesn't say anything about our seeking. It's also unclear whose [demands of what's possible] belong to. Literally, it just says that the demands exist. However, it's reasonable to say that it's about our demands, and it's [what's possible] to us and to them too.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the only rules are what is possible. There are no rules set out by a governing body (i.e. decree) or established by routine.  Each individual is only limited by what he or she sees as the stark boundaries of reality.

Answer (score 0):

It simply mean that there are no pre defined rules and the execution is done as per the demand and the possibility of the action.